# Connection speed from ISP company vs router speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, speed

I was looking around on Amazon and found a router that said it claims to have "lightning fast 1.9 Gbps speed". Currently Comcast sends out 105 Mbps. So does that mean the router can get up to 1.9 Gbps  or get 1.9 Gbps no matter what speed is sent out.

If the second one is true, then I really need to catch up on my stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up `Gbps` and `Mbps`.

- `Gbps` means means gigabits per second.
- `Mbps` means means megabits per second.

And 1 Gbps translates to 1000 Mbps.

So if the router can handle 1.9 Gbps that is about 1,900 Mbps which is about 18 times more than Comcast’s 105 Mbps.

Which means that when you get your 105 Mbps from Comcast the router will be more than capable to handle that speed. It does not mean it will magically speed up your connection. That speed rating for the router most likely will only be seen when you use the router on your local area network running at gigabit Ethernet speeds.

Comment: As a side note it is quite likely that the 1.9Gbps is the aggregate data throughput of the system-on-a-chip in the router which would mean that it can sustain two gigabit speed data transfers (between machines on different ports) at once.  Good if you are transferring a lot of data across the network between various machines.